# Rolling a dice in python n times

Tags: python

I'd like to create code that will 'roll' number_of_dice times and find the sum of the rolls. This is what I have. I'm getting an error when I do "sum = sum + roll" that there's unsupported operand types for +: built_in_function_or_method and int. How can I solve this?

```
for i in range(0,number_of_dice):
    roll = random.randint(1,number_of_sides + 1)
    sum = sum + roll
    return sum
```

Comment: As you develop you may want to look into [generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) and use the inbuilt `sum` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a built in function `sum` that returns the sum of numbers given as a sequence. Since you have not declared a variable `sum` it is trying to `+` that built in function and a number `roll` which is not permitted. You need to define the variable before the loop:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(0,number_of_dice):
    roll = random.randint(1,number_of_sides + 1)
    sum = sum + roll

return sum
```

Note that you are supposed to return after the loop, not from inside the loop. Also, if you don't want to shadow the built in function `sum` then you can use a different name for your variable.

Comment: Don't shadow `sum`. Who knows what that could break?

Comment: @SamyBencherif if this code is inside a small function then you can shadow built-in in small local scope without much problem. But if the scope if bigger than there could be problem. Obviously we can't say the situation here without much context. That's why I placed the last line of answer.

Comment: But if you are trying to introduce a new person to coding you should just break them of the habit of using built-ins as variable names.

Comment: taskinoor @PyNEwbie, good points. I'm concerned that some default function might use sum, so this is the kind of problem that might go unnoticed for a long time  and crop later if such function is added.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
import random

def sum_of_dice(number_of_dice, n_sides_on_die=6):
    return sum([random.choice(range(1, n_sides_on_die + 1))
                for i in range(number_of_dice)])
```

Comment: There really is no need to create a list - remove `[ ]` and you have a generator expression. `randint()` does the same as the `choice(range(...))`